# What does org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException error mean in jMeter summary results?

Tags: jmeter

I am doing a load testing on a website and after starting my test on remote devices and recording the responses on a log file, I am getting this response on some requests:

Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I concluded that it isn't a server error but rather a client one. To fix the problem of not being able to overload the server, I changed the jmeter remote settings - I stopped the master computer from generating summary reports during the running time (i.e. during the time he was receiving test results from slave computers), and turned off the View Result Tree generation also.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpHostConnectException](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/HttpHostConnectException.html) is a subtype of [ConnectException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html):

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port).

It means that JMeter tries to establish the connection and the application under test doesn't accept it.

There could be several reasons behind it:

1. You're sending more requests than application under test (or its hosting web/application server) is capable of serving. You need to inspect your application or its underlying container logs and configuration and ensure it has [proper settings in order to handle the anticipated load](https://stackify.com/web-performance-optimization/)
2. The system under test is overloaded in terms of CPU, RAM or Network. You need to ensure that the application under test has enough headroom to operate, at this stage you might need to upgrade hardware if this is the bottleneck. Make sure to monitor essential performance metrics, it can be done using i.e. built-in monitoring tools of the operating system where you application is running or via an [APM tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) or with [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test).
3. Your application code is the bottleneck, i.e. there is an inefficient function or some [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) maximum number setting which limits the number of connections which can be served. Again you need to inspect your application logs or use a [profiling tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry to see what's going on when your application is under the load

Comment: So, that is basically a server error (caused because of the server) but that doesn't mean that the server is down. I am increasing the number of threads but server response code is never 503 or something like that. I get 200 response codes or the error I've mentioned, no matter what. Why is that happening? Could that be related to the fact that the server might be protected from DDoS attacks?

Answer (score 0):

Upon adding
5 seconds Start up delay and
Duration as 1
in Jmeter I did not get the above exception.